# Code igniter printing array size

Tags: codeigniter

In my controller, I am passing values to array like this `$this->load->view('example',$data[test]);`

In my view, I am trying to get array size of test so I did it like this,

`echo count($test);` I have 10 rows in my data base but my array is printing 1.

Comment: `$this->load->view('example',$data[test]);` needs to be `$this->load->view('example',$data['test']);` otherwise it thinks you are trying to use the constant named `test` not the array index. Make sure you are correctly assigning it as well. Always develop with `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL` as it would have errored and notified you of your error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you missed `$` in your code you have given. Just try this,

```
echo count($test);
```

Comment: :It was a typo, If I have missed $,it would given me a error.

Comment: @user2261231 What error are you receiving?